# HTC One internal storage performing very slowly

Tags: performance, htc-one, internal-sd

Using A1 SD, I can see that my HTC One (M7)'s 'internal SD card' (ie, the embedded storage) is incredibly slow compared to other benchmarks listed by anonymous users for the same phone. I'm only getting  6.68MB/s read, and 2.76MB/s write. However, others are getting 50MB/s read and 33MB/s write (for the same HTC One M7 and the same storage location)

Any idea why my phone might be performing so slowly? And how might I improve its speeds?

Its important to note that I've run this diagnosis because for months I've put up with slow speeds and only now getting around to doing something about it. Quite often when saving a photo or a video it will hang for many minutes. I typically find that performance is worse when the card is nearing on full, but now even clearing out storage doesn't seem to give back much performance.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting my phone did the trick.

This isn't a very good answer, as I don't know the root cause. I'm going to slowly add back apps and see if there's a particular one that might have been a bit IO greedy. So far I've added most back and its still fantastically fast again. Haven't signed into Facebook yet... I've always had my suspicions...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the HTC one Max and have had this exact same problem as you describe.  Really slow laggy performance on the phone and was considering a new one even though I am happy with the Max apart from the lag.  I ended up buying a faster SDCard to see if that improved things then tried A1 Bench.  My SDCard was fast 70MB/s read 30MB/s write but the internal storage was slow as treacle reading at 6MB/s.  I did a factory reset last night and now the internal storage is running 43MB/s read 32MB/s write.  I uninstalled the FB app and messenger before the first benchmarks as well so dont think it is that.

I didnt exactly have lots of rubbish apps installed anyway so its strange, I did read somewhere that its best to do a factory reset after upgrading to lollypop so maybe its just that.  I have put most of the apps I regularly use back on except for FB so far and benchmarks are still looking good.  I may put FB app back on as prefer it to just using chrome.

What we really need is something like windows resource monitor that shows all the processes running that we can sort by disk io, memory and cpu usage so when its running dog slow can see exactly what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on HTC One X. After trying many things, the action that seems to have fixed the problem was deleting two big (almost 500MB each) thumbnail-metadata files for the images.

I hope this helps others, too.